# How to set a specific date range picker

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code, there are no errors, but i have a doubt, i was trying to create a default date range picker, to be more specific, a 7 days range, i mean a date picker that only selects weeks, so i couldnt select more or less than 7 days in the date picker.

But i couldnt code this, i need some help haha.

```
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRangePick;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import '../constants.dart';
import '../components/chart_bar.dart';

class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsScreenState createState() => _DetailsScreenState();
}

class _DetailsScreenState extends State<DetailsScreen> {
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now();

  Future displayDateRangePicker(context) async {
    final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePick.showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialFirstDate: _startDate,
      initialLastDate: _endDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
      setState(() {
        _startDate = picked[0];
        _startDate = picked[1];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _detailsScreen() {
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kBlackColor,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    '${DateFormat('d / MM / y').format(_startDate)} - ${DateFormat('d / MM / y').format(_endDate)}',
                    style: kWhite20RegularTextStyle,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await displayDateRangePicker(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return _detailsScreen();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `selectableDayPredicate` 
Working demo limit range between start date and end date, you can see range outside limit is gray out

code snippet

```
bool checkLimit(DateTime limitDay) {
    if (limitDay.isBefore(_startDate)) {
      return false;
    } else if (limitDay.isAfter(_endDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future displayDateRangePicker(context) async {
    final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePick.showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialFirstDate: _startDate,
        initialLastDate: _endDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
        lastDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectableDayPredicate: checkLimit
        );
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRangePick;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsScreenState createState() => _DetailsScreenState();
}

class _DetailsScreenState extends State<DetailsScreen> {
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now();

  bool checkLimit(DateTime limitDay) {
    if (limitDay.isBefore(_startDate)) {
      return false;
    } else if (limitDay.isAfter(_endDate)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future displayDateRangePicker(context) async {
    final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePick.showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialFirstDate: _startDate,
        initialLastDate: _endDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 10),
        lastDate: DateTime.now(),
        selectableDayPredicate: checkLimit
        );
    if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
      setState(() {
        _startDate = picked[0];
        _startDate = picked[1];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _detailsScreen() {
      return Scaffold(
        //backgroundColor: kBlackColor,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    '${DateFormat('d / MM / y').format(_startDate)} - ${DateFormat('d / MM / y').format(_endDate)}',
                    //style: kWhite20RegularTextStyle,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    await displayDateRangePicker(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return _detailsScreen();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: DetailsScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```